# Can't open project properties google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, properties, storage, project

I've deleted in file->project properties -> project Properties the properties key and value and from then I can't open project properties and script not working. 
How reset/delete the script properties?

I've tried copy the project, but I'm using the version of project and only the latest version is copied to the new project. I'need the oldest version of my project.

Please help me!

this is the link of spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/a/kierowca.pl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnTGczwoMaewdEp3WUdmWU5UdFpmYk1JOVkyR1g0dmc

name of project
zleceniaZewnSystemZlecen1

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1519) where bad keys in the script properties are prevent reads/writes and the dialog from loading.